# Does the thickness of the soap film gets increase if we stretch it more and in case of pricking it?

Tags: fluid-statics

When there is a rectangle film whose three adjacents sides are being fixed by wire , the last one is being able to move freely by a movable bar , if we consider the film to be having a thickness h , when we move the bar we know that film will stretch more , but in doing so will the thickness gets decreased so as to conserve volume ? Is it true? This happens too in case we prick the centre of a circular film then as the prick hole gets bigger the thickness of the remaining film gets increased progressively ?

Comment: Yes, volume in liquids is conserved except in cases of enormous pressure.

Comment: @Chemomechanics does the thickness is increasing like in a regular way that is suppose intially it has thickness (t) then a bit later the thickness all over that area will change to (t') ? Or its sort of non uniform over the area ?

Comment: Nonuniform, tending toward equilibrium. This is a complex fluid dynamics problem that you'd have to model and solve.